# Parse dictionary with different kinds of values

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a Json that returns something like this:

```
"Name" : {
 "1" : [ an array of class1 objects ],
 "2" : [ an array of class2 objects ],
 "3" : [ an array of class3 objects ],
}
```

If every key has a value of the same type, I use this:

```
public Dictionary<int, class1[]> object1 { get; set; }
```

But I don't know how to do it if every key has a different class of object. How can I do it?

Comment: Why not using a `string` key for any case?

Comment: I suggest either creating a JsonConverter (assuming Newtonsoft JSON since you haven't said which library you're using), or using dynamic.

Comment: @Diego can you specify what you mean?

Comment: @DavidTG Use a common base class. If `object` is the best fit, `Dictionary<int, List<object>> object1`.

Comment: What about `Dictionary<int,IList>`?

Comment: My first response is, albeit that this is valid JSON, it isn't necessarily *good* JSON. Do you have any way of altering the JSON that gets returned; specifying different kvps with the different types in? The other option is to have it as a `Dictionary<string, object[]>` and try casting each one as you go through when parsing.

Comment: @john I use Newtonsoft, is on the tags but Im editing the post to get it clear :) I use the jSonConverter but I need to have the class on which Im gonna convert.

Comment: Do class1, class2 and class3 have anything in common with each other?

Comment: @BrianRogers is like class 1 2 and 3 are plane, car and boat and the main class is vehicles. So no technically, but they must be together

Comment: For completely unstructured JSON consider using [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use an array of objects like this

```
public Dictionary<int, object[]> ObjectsDictionary { get; set; }
```

I wrote an example below note that in my example I use a string key however you can use int instead there won't be any problem

```
    class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary ObjectsDictionary { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjectsDictionary = new Dictionary();
            Class1[] classes1 =
            {
                new Class1 {X = 54, Y = 454},
                new Class1 {X = 1, Y = 2}
            };
            Classe2[] classes2 =
            {
                new Classe2 {IsSomthing = true, Name = "String 1 class 2"},
                new Classe2 {IsSomthing = false, Name = "String 2 class 2"}
            };

            ObjectsDictionary.Add("Key 1",classes1);
            ObjectsDictionary.Add("Key 2",classes2);

        }

    }
    class Class1
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }

    class Classe2
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsSomthing { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to work with the parser! But when I try ObjectsDictionary[0] I get  Error CS0176 Member  cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead